Powershell unable to execute sytem commands like ipconfig
Relatively new to this sort of thing but I'm having a problem with Powershell that after hours of troubleshooting I cannot resolve. I'm unable to execute commands like ipconfig, whoami, ping, etc. in a normal or admin powershell window.  When I try to run them straight up (e.g., type in ipconfig I get an error:
ipconfig : The term 'ipconfig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ipconfig
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ipconfig:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

When I run the commands with the full path (e.g., & C:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe), PS runs them in a new window that opens and then immediately closes.
This came up as I was trying to set up SSH for Home Assistant I'm running on a Raspberry Pi.  I can connect, I just can't do it with ssh username@IP, which sent me down a powershell rabbit hole.
Everything that's wrong in PS works fine in the command prompt.  I could probably ignore this but I'd like to fix it - being new to this sort of thing, I want to try to limit the number of things that can go wrong and I feel like having a broken powershell is a bad foundation.
I'm on Windows 11, PS version 5.1.  Everything else in my system seems to be working fine.  This problem persists across both my personal and work account, and when running PS with no profile (-NoProfile).
I feel like it could be something to do with my PATH variables.  I ran $env:PATH -split ';', which gave me this list of paths:
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

ANY help would be greatly appreciated -- this is driving me nuts.  Thanks in advance.
Here's what I've tried:

Checked execution policy, which is set to RemoteSigned
Verified System32 is present in PATH
Checked for issues with Powershell profiles, reset the profile, tried running with no profile.
Verified PS was set to FullLanguage
Ran commands with full path - this is where they opened then immediately closed.
Checked System32 permissions.
Verified filetype associations for .exe are correct.
Checked for an alias for any of the commands that won't won't work.
Attempted to repair powershell with Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber This asked me if I wanted to install NuGet, I said yes, and then after that everything working -- until I closed and tried in a new PS window.
Ran sfc /scannow and DISM, repaired issues.
Checked for malware and tried with the firewall off.


The symptoms are mysterious but do at least in part suggest that they're related to the value of $env:PATH. It's unclear how reinstalling the PowerShellGet module is related to this, but since you say things returned to normal afterwards for the remainder of the session, I suggest copying the value of $env:PATH at that time to the clipboard, starting a new session, and assigning it to $env:PATH there, to see if that alone makes the problem go away, as a first troubleshooting step.

Thanks - this is a good idea and I wish I had done it when it was working, but I'm not able to replicate the results from reinstalling PowerShellGet.  When I try it the same way I did before, I get this:
WARNING: The version '1.4.8.1' of module 'PackageManagement' is currently in use. Retry the operation after closing the applications.
If I try running ipconfig or other commands after that, same issue as above.

Just starting a new session should allow you to re-run the command without error.

This very well may be just my own confusion, but I cannot replicate the working powershell I thought I'd gotten during my original troubleshooting.  Running the same command now, Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber, I get this:
Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "0" argument(s): "The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object."

Continuing to try and resolve this, and I've found that powershell works fine in a python virtual environment within vs code -- unsure if that points to any solution.
